# Interface/pinout of a smartphone camera module?

Tags: camera, interface, pinout

I am wondering where, if any, I can get information regarding interfacing/connecting with a smartphone camera module. For example, [this](http://www.etradesupply.com/oem-samsung-galaxy-s4-gt-i9500-back-camera.html) camera module is a replacement for SGS4 and I can clearly see that it had a connector. Does anyone knows where I can find manufacturers of such modules, and hopefully how to connect and use them in a different project using a microcontroller (or similar?)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no expert on this, but I *think* it's industry standard, and it's called [MIPI](http://www.mipi.org/specifications/camera-interface). Many of the fancy new ARM SOCs have direct support (read pins allocated) for this interface I believe. If there's anything vendor specific about it, good luck figuring it out with a datasheet - your best bet is to contact the distributor / manufacturer directly for advice in that case.

Comment: Will you happen to know how one can find who are the manufacturers of different camera modules? (ie If I am looking on specific smartphone and want to know who made that part on that phone?)

Comment: no... maybe email the distributor or phone manufacturer, or tear a phone down

Answer (score 1):

Try Wikipedia too  https://www.electroschematics.com/9767/mobile-phone-camera-interface/

There are several standards, probably more to come.